# python 3.7 printing binary string shows strange character

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex

in python 3.7, when I execute the following statement:

```
print(b'\x80\x51\x01\x00')
```

I get

```
b'\x80Q\x01\x00'
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because \x51 is hexadecimal of 'Q'. \x51 is hexadecimal and its decimal is 81 and it stands for 'Q'.

Answer (score 1):

A binary string in Python always begins with b.

The Q is decoded because \x51 or 0x51 in ascii is Q.

In order to print a binary string, you first need to decode it with string.decode():

```
print(b'\x51\x52\x53'.decode('ascii'))
```

In the case of your string, it can not be decoded as ASCII because 0x80 is not a valid character. (ASCII only goes up to 0x7F)

Comment: is there way to print out the hex representation as-is? print(b'\x80\x51\x01\x00') shows only '80510100'